# Spark connectors from Azure Databricks to Snowflake using AzureAD login

Tags: azure, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am trying to connect below Spark connectors from Databricks to Snowflake. On the Snowflake side, I can access the account using "Login via AzureAD" which are my Azure account credentials.

But, trying to provide the same spark connectors for Snowflake is not working.

```json
options = {
  "sfUrl": url,
  "sfUser": my azure username,
  "sfPassword": corresponding pwd,
  "sfDatabase": db,
  "sfSchema": schema,
  "sfWarehouse": warehouse,
  "Role":role
}
```

Please note if I have logged in using service account details created on the Snowflake side then that is working.

Any pointer on how to connect to Snowflake using my credentials from Databricks?

Comment: It's not working because you are using SSO while you login with your own account. Just add `("authenticator" , "externalbrowser")` and it should work